# Microsoft Surface Rotation Bug?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-surface

I have a Microsoft Surface device that crashes under a specific scenario. I'm a developer, and have filed a report with Microsoft. However, they are having trouble reproducing the issue. I'm wondering if anyone else out there, who owns a Surface, can reproduce the following crash:

1. Reboot the Surface (make sure to be in landscape mode).
2. From the Start Menu, open up the desktop - this is needed so that you can snap the application.
3. Open up the Windows Mail Application and put it into "filled" mode, where it takes up 2/3 of the screen, and is side-by-side with the desktop.
4. Create a new email message - this should bring up the soft keyboard.
5. Rotate the screen into portrait mode to cause a resize. Rotate back to Landscape.
6. Mail should crash, taking down the Windows GUI Shell.  If it doesn't crash, try rotating the device a few times (landscape -> portrait -> landscape etc)

Edit: I should add that if your device crashes, you can "un-crash" it by logging out and logging back in. To do this press the Windows button and power button at the same time (or press ctrl-alt-del). You should then see options, one of which is log out.

Comment: Giving it a try... How do I go into filled mode?

Comment: When you have mail at full screen, swipe inwards a little bit from the left side and then swipe back outwards. You should see the desktop there. Drag it all the way over to the right hand side and drop it there. Mail should then take up 2/3 of the screen, with the desktop taking up the rest.

Comment: No luck reproducing so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since tried this on two other Surface devices.

One was at a Microsoft Store, where I could not reproduce the problem.  Unfortunately I didn't try it on more than one device at the MS Store, and I also do not live near any MS Stores (to try more).

The other is on my current Surface device, which Microsoft sent me in exchange for my old one - I am able to reproduce the problem on my new device.

So there you have it.  This seems to be something that only I can reproduce.  No one else has reported this issue, and it seems Microsoft (MSDN Support) cannot reproduce it.